# How to give effect to local machine image using Caman js?

Tags: camanjs

I am new to caman js. I want to edit image residing at my local machine using caman js. I searched for it but could not find appropriate code. I also went through tutorial of caman js.
link: http://camanjs.com/guides/
Can anyone please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided gives the information you are looking for. If I understand your question correctly, these are the basic steps you need to take.

1. Make sure the Camanjs plugin is included in your project.
2. Have an img or canvas element on your working DOM
3. After the DOM is ready Initialize Camanjs by passing to it either a selector or DOM element. Here is the relevant code to the link you provided:

   ```
   Caman("#image-id", function () {
       // Setup whatever options or image processing you want here
       // Make sure to render after
       this.brightness(5).render();
   });
   ```

Your question asks about a file on your local machine. From my understanding, your image has to be present in the DOM to work on it with Camanjs. Therefore, your image should be located somewhere your html/javascript can find. (i.e. 'img/myLocalPicture.jpg' relative to your .html file)

For me, looking at the source code of Camanjs was very helpful as well as looking at the API docs: http://camanjs.com/api/

If you want a more specific answer please rephrase your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a file using the HTML5 File API.

If you are using JQuery, the following will allow you to browse for a local file, and then apply an effect to it.  (You don't need jquery, this is just a feature of HTML5)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/caman.full.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="myimage" alt="Image go here" />
        <form>
            <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        $("#fileinput").change(function(evt) {
            var image = evt.target.files[0];
            $("#myimage").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(image));
            processImage();
        });

        function processImage() {
            Caman("#myimage", function() {
                // Perform your effects here
            });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```